# Coefficients in Fourier sine series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider this example,

> Two infinite grounded plates lie parallel to the $xz$ plane, one at $y = 0$, the other ar $y = a$ plane. The left end at $x = 0$ is closed off with an infinite strip insulated from two plates and maintained at a specific potential $V_0(y)$. Find potential inside this slot.

To solve for potential I need to solve

$$\dfrac{\partial^2 V }{\partial x^2} +\dfrac{\partial^2 V }{\partial y^2} = 0$$

For boundary conditions,

$$\begin {cases}\text{V = 0 when y = 0}\\\text{ V = 0 when y = a}\\\text{V = $V_0$(y) when x = 0}\\\text{$V \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$}\end{cases}$$

Using separation of variables, 
I got

$$V(x, y) = Ce^{-kx}\sin (ky)$$

Where $k = \dfrac{n\pi}{a},\ n \in \Bbb Z_{+}$

Since there is no single value of $n$ for which $V$ satisfy condition $4$, we write

$$V(x,y) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}C_n\exp\left({-\dfrac{n\pi}{a}x}\right)\sin \left(\dfrac{n\pi}{a}y\right) \tag 1$$

Then,

$$V_0(y) = V(0,y) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}C_n\sin \left(\dfrac{n\pi}{a}y\right)$$
$$\int_0^a V_0(y)\sin \left(\dfrac{n^\prime\pi}{a}y\right) dy = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}C_n \int_0^a\sin \left(\dfrac{n^\prime\pi}{a}y\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{a}y\right) dy = \dfrac a2C_{n^\prime} \tag 2$$

Where $n^\prime$ is some +ve integer.

But then the book claims that potential is given by $(1)$ for $$C_n = \dfrac2a\int_0^a V_0(y)\sin \left(\dfrac{n \pi}{a}y\right) dy, n \in \Bbb Z$$

I did not understand this, we solved $C_n$ from one specific $n^\prime$ not for all $n \in \Bbb Z_+$. How are we saying that $2$ is true for all $n$ ?

One more small thing, why did we integrate from $0$ to $a$ not something else ?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero If you asking about line below $1$ it is  to find $V_0(y)$, which is only dependant on $y$ but I did not understand what you mean to say.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Because the $k$'s are same ?

Comment: oh dear!  How sill of me.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the reasoning behind integrating (projecting) both sides in $(2)$? When you simplify the expression, you should end up with an expression for $C$ in terms of only one index, not both.

Comment: @Kajelad Yes I got an expression for $C$ in terms of only one index, i.e $$C_n = \dfrac2a\int_0^a V_0(y)\sin \left(\dfrac{n\pi}{a}y\right) dy, n \in \Bbb Z$$. I fixed the typo.

Comment: You're trying to expand $V_0(y)$ in terms of its fourier series, so when you say "n' is some integer": $n'$ is *any* non-negative integer, which define the fourier coefficients $C_n$. The only time you'd get a single $n'=m$ is when $V_0(y)=\sin(m\pi y/a)$. The integration region is on 0-a because that's the interval on which you're expanding your boundary condition in terms of its fourier series.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks I get that. If you can write an answer I will accept it.